# different pips are used between `pip --version` and `which pip`

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Here's something weird happening on my box:

```
(base) ben@Ben:~/.local/bin$ echo $PATH
/home/ben/.local/bin:/home/ben/anaconda3/bin:/home/ben/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
(base) ben@Ben:~/.local/bin$ which -a pip
/home/ben/anaconda3/bin/pip
(base) ben@Ben:~/.local/bin$ pip --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
(base) ben@Ben:~/.local/bin$ /home/ben/anaconda3/bin/pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /home/ben/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Why are different instances of `pip` were called? `which pip` returned the correct version that I want, but when I call `pip`, it runs the one installed by default in the system. How do I fix it?

I have Ubuntu 19.10, Anaconda 4.8.3, Python 3.7.6.

Comment: Have you, by any chance created an alias in you `.bashrc` for `pip`?

Comment: yes I have `alias pip=pip3` when I first installed Ubuntu

Comment: That was it! I got it now. If you can create an answer, I'll mark it quickly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`which` cannot detect aliases and since your `pip` points to the system `python3` instead of `python2`, I suspect that you have an alias in your `.bashrc` for `pip`. Delete that and it should work as expected.